# Geometry of Complex Numbers (lemma)

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Recently I found very interesting lemma, unfortunately without proof. I will be grateful if you help me to prove it.
Let triangle ABC have incenter $I$ and circumcircle $Γ$. Lines $AI, BI, CI$
meet $Γ$ again at $D, E, F$ . If $Γ$ is the unit circle of the complex plane then there exists
$x, y, z ∈ C$ satisfying
$a = x^2, b = y^2, c = z^2$ and $d = −yz, e = −zx, f = −xy$.

Comment: What are $a, b, c,...$?

Comment: $a,b,c$ are complex coordinates of $A,B,C$

Comment: See Evan Chen's article here: https://blog.evanchen.cc/2018/02/28/revisiting-arc-midpoints-in-complex-numbers/

Comment: @dodoturkoz Good catch !

Comment: @iskander Have you noticed that intersection of angle bissector $AI$ for example is the midpoint of the arc circle $BC$ not containing $A$ ?

Answer (score 0):

To be sure that I get it, check me? 
Since $\angle CBD$ and $\angle BCD$ based on equal arcs, then $BD= CD$.
Thus
\begin{align*}
(b-d)(\overline{b-d}) &= (c-d)(\overline{c-d})\\
\text{,by circle equation, we get } \bar b = \frac{1}{b},\text{ } \bar{c}=\frac{1}{c}\text{ and } \bar d = \frac{1}{d}.\\
(b-d)(\frac{1}{b}-\frac{1}{d}) &= (c-d)(\frac{1}{c}-\frac{1}{d})\\
\frac{b}{d}+\frac{d}{b}&= \frac{c}{d}+\frac{d}{c}\\
c(b^2+d^2) &= b(c^2+d^2)\\
d^2 &= bc
\end{align*}
Analogously we get $e^2 = ca$ and $f^2 = ab$.
We pick an arbitrary choice for $x$ first. Then, of the two choices of $y$, we pick the one such that $-xy = f$. Similarly, for the two choices of $z$, we pick the one such that $-xz = e$. Since $AD\perp EF$, we get
\begin{align*}
\overrightarrow{\rm AD }\cdot \overrightarrow{\rm EF} &= \frac{1}{2}[(a-d)(\overline{e-f})+(\overline{a-d})(e-f)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}[(x^2-d)(\overline{zx-xy}+(\overline{x^2-d})(zx-xy)]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}[(x^2-d)(\frac{1}{zx}-\frac{1}{xy})+(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{d})(zx-xy)]\\
&=\frac{(x^2-d)(y-z)}{2x}(\frac{1}{yz}+\frac{1}{x})
\end{align*}
Which gives us $d = -yz$.